# Change "close" link style or color when user has already cast a vote

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, hyperlinks, vote-to-delete

When I come across a question that in my opinion needs be closed, I click on the `close` link below the question, choose a reason and confirm.
But sometimes, I already have cast a vote to close the question, and I realize that only when the choices' window displays:
`You have already voted to close this question`

I suggest changing the appearance of the `close` links to make it obvious if you have already cast a vote to close a question.
I see 2 possible options:

- write the link in a different color (such as what is already done when you upvote or downvote a question or answer)
- write the link in bold:

  > **close (3)**

The same thing may also apply for delete-votes.

Comment: It happens with the "delete" link to. Sometimes, I vote to delete a question I have already voted to delete.

Answer (score 3):

I also sometimes find myself revisiting questions I've already voted to close, but I don't think it's really a problem. Making a UI change to save a single click in this rare case seems unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is quite rare, I have clicked to close questions which I've already voted for plenty of times. It would be a handy little feature, wouldn't hurt anything, it would just help.

Comment: The only hurt would be an extra nanosecond used when the page is loaded.